One-dimensional configuration of 6 points is projection of quadrilateral set
I am working on the following exercise of Algorithms in invariant theory by Sturmfels. "A configuration of six points $a=(a_1:a_2:a_3), ..., f = (f_1, f_2, f_3)$ in
the projective plane $P^2$ is called a quadrilateral set if the triples ace, adf,
bcf and bde are collinear (see figure). The one-dimensional configuration
$a=(a_1:a_2), ..., f = (f_1, f_2)$ in Example 3.2.10 is the projection of a
quadrilateral set if and only if there exist complex numbers
$a_3; b_3; c_3; d_3; e_3; f_3$ such that $(a_1:a_2:a_3), ..., (f_1, f_2, f_3)$ is a
quadrilateral set. Prove that this geometric property is equivalent to the
vanishing of the invariant I = -[ad][cf][be]-[af][bc][de]..
I did the following:
I used the following configuration and I write 1 for P1, ... .

WLOG the points are on the line z = 0. So $1 = [x_1, y_1, 0]$ etc.
Let $\tilde{1}, \cdots \tilde{6}$ denote the point in P^2 with projection 1, ..., 6. Then $\tilde{1} = 1 + \mu_1 P$ with $P$ the point from which we project (an unknown as well).
Since $\tilde{1}, ..., \tilde{6}$ is a quadrilateral set, we have:
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
    [\tilde{1} \tilde{2} \tilde{3}] = 0 \\
    [\tilde{1} \tilde{5} \tilde{6}] = 0 \\
    [\tilde{2} \tilde{4} \tilde{6}] = 0 \\
    [\tilde{3} \tilde{4} \tilde{5}] = 0 \\
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
This holds iff
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lll}
    [1 + \mu_1 P  & 2 + \mu_2 P & 3 + \mu_3 P] = 0 \\
\cdots & & \\ 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
If and only if
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lllllll}
    [1 & 2 & \mu_3 P] + [1 & \mu_2 P & 3] + [\mu_1 P & 2 & 3] = 0 \\
\cdots & & & & & &  \\ 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$ where we used that the bracket is zero if it contains P more than once and that 1, 2 and 3 have a 0 on the last line.
This holds iff
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
    [1 2] \mu_3 P_z - [1 3] \mu_2 P_z + [2 3] \mu_1 P_z = 0
\\ \cdots \\ 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
We can put this conditions in a matrix:
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
[23] & -[13] & [12] & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
[5 6] & 0 & 0 & 0 & [16] & [15] \\
0 & [4 6] & 0 & [26] & 0 & [24] \\
0 & 0 & [45] & [35] & [34] & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}  \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \\ \mu_4 \\ \mu_5 \\ \mu_6 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{gather}
I don't know how to proceed.
